# Calculate DF using Lucene doesn't work

Tags: lucene, tf-idf

I have an index with 2 docs at the moment (will add some more after everything will work ok).
I try to `calculate the df` for a specific term but I get all the time the total number of docs in the index as a result.for debug purpose I entered a unique string in one doc so the result of the df should be **1**. but, it returns **2**. at the end of the process I'll need a `tf/idf` score for every word in the index.

I've tried the following code:

```
public void calcDF (String term) throws IOException
{

     //open the index file
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File("d:/index"));
    //create a reader
    IndexReader ir = IndexReader.open(dir);
    //for debug
    System.out.println("num of docs in index : " + ir.maxDoc()); 
    Term t = new Term("content",term);
    int df = ir.docFreq(t);
}
```

Tried also with `IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(ir);` instead of `indexReader` but no luck.

**P.S:** I'm using `lucene 3.5`

Comment: I suggest you try to debug this with [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/). If you enter the query there, do you really only get one hit?

Comment: Could you describe what the problem was so that this question is useful for others that find it in the archive?

Comment: solution:programming error,not related to lucene at all.